# How to replace div with a particular class with editable text area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

How can I replace the `div` tag with an `input` tag using javascript?

I have the following html markup:

```
<div class="divclass">"Same text"</div>
```

I want to replace it with

```
<input class="divclass">"Same text"</input>
```

As I understood so far, I need to use jQuery `.replaceWith` method. But I do not know how to do that.

Comment: INPUTs are void elements, this isn't valid HTML markup. So it should be: `<input class="divclass" value="Same text">`

Comment: Don't know but good question 1 up for question

Comment: Have you checked the documentation and examples on the [jQuery website](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)?

Comment: Why do you want to replace the div with an input? if you want to modify the text inside, you can just add an input or a textarea inside the div tag

Comment: Couldn't you use: `<div class="divclass" contenteditable>"Same text"</div>`  http://jsfiddle.net/2W5KD/  ???

Comment: As far as I know (this goes back to a year or 2), `contenteditable` does not have full support on all browsers. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @SparoHawk http://caniuse.com/#search=contenteditable%20

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('div.divclass').replaceWith(function(){
return $('<input />').addClass($(this).attr("class")).text($(this).text());
});
```

By the way, inputs are void method so you won't be able to see any change regarding "same text".

But if you do this:

```
$('div.divclass').replaceWith(function () {
    return $('<input />').addClass($(this).attr("class")).val($(this).text());
});
```

you'll notice the change.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RmfHg/

Comment: @SparolHawk That was an huge edit. you should have posted it as an answer not edited the answer change it all! +Amit if you liked the edit, do it yourself adding the fiddle as u did prior.